# How do I dynamically add additional `sidebarMenu`s with an action button in shiny (shinydashboard) using `renderMenu`?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

Here is the code I am working from:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(),
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(menuItem("Home", tabName = "home")),
                            sidebarMenuOutput("menu"),
                            actionButton('add_menu', 'Add Menu'))
body <- dashboardBody()

ui <- dashboardPage(header = header, body = body, sidebar = sidebar)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  shinyInput <- function(name, id) paste(name, id, sep = "_")
  counter <- reactiveValues(counter_value = 0L)
  
  observeEvent(input$add_menu, {
    counter$counter_value <- counter$counter_value + 1L
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$add_menu, {
    output$menu <- renderMenu({
                        sidebarMenu(
                          menuItem(paste("Menu", counter$counter_value),
                          value = shinyInput("new_menu", counter$counter_value)
                          ))
})
     
  })


}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Currently when you press the `actionButton`, a new menu will appear under the home tab, and with each subsequent click, the name of this menu increases by increments of 1. This is because `output$menu` is being overwritten with each subsequent click of the button `add_menu`. Instead, with every click of `add_menu` I would like additional/new menus to appear, so two clicks would have a home page and two menus. Three clicks would have a home page and 3 menus, etc... I am unsure how to accomplish this, I considered using one of the `apply` family of functions but was unsuccessful. The goal here is to click an action button in the sidebar, and add additional menus to the dashboard sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will meet your needs.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader()
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(#sidebarMenu(menuItem("Home", tabName = "home")),
                            sidebarMenuOutput(outputId = "dy_menu"),
                            actionButton('add_menu', 'Add Menu'))
body <- dashboardBody()

ui <- dashboardPage(header = header, body = body, sidebar = sidebar)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  menu_vals = reactiveValues(menu_list = NULL)
  counter <- reactiveValues(counter_value = 0L)
  
  output$dy_menu <- renderMenu({
    menu_list <- list(
      menuItem("Add Menu Items", tabName = "main", selected = TRUE),
      menu_vals$menu_list)
    sidebarMenu(.list = menu_list)
  })
  
  observeEvent(eventExpr = input$add_menu,
               handlerExpr = {
                 counter$counter_value <- counter$counter_value + 1L
                 menu_vals$menu_list[[length(menu_vals$menu_list) + 1]] <- menuItem(paste("Menu", counter$counter_value),
                                                                                    tabName = paste0("Menu", counter$counter_value)) 
                 
               })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]